# Unity3D: Field currentActivity or type signature not found

Tags: unity-game-engine

after upgrading my unity version to 2019.2.17 i get this error:

> Exception: Field currentActivity or type signature  not found
>   UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass,
>   System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean
>   isStatic)

when trying to get currentActivity with this code:

```
    // Retrieve the UnityPlayer class.
    unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

    // Retrieve the UnityPlayerActivity object ( a.k.a. the current context )
    unityActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: from which unity version did you upgrade?

Comment: Add try-catch around it. In a latest versions of Unity it starts crashing when you call "currentActivity" in the editor. It will work eventually on a real device.

Comment: I got the same error. For me, I think it happend after my pro license expired

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, and after my head went all bold, I noticed that I didn't get this problem when I switch off the device simulator!!!

Hope this be of help.